# Is there a continuous bijective function $\ f: [0,1) \rightarrow \Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Now I'm fairly certain there is no continuous bijective function as there is an issue with the fact that the interval is half open.

Not exactly sure what to do from here.

Comment: The function $f|_{(0,1)}$ is continuous with connected domain, and therefore image.

Comment: Not really different from thew answers below, but a continuous one-to-one function from $[0,1)$ into the reals must be monotone.

Comment: No, but you can have a continuous bijection $f:[0,1)\to\Bbb{R}^*$ where $\Bbb{R}^*$ is the reals + point at infinity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** If there were, $f\bigl((0,1)\bigr)=\mathbb R\setminus\bigl\{f(0)\bigr\}$ would be connected.

Answer (score 0):

If there were such a function, then $g:(0,1)\to \mathbb R\setminus \{f(0)\}$ would be a continuous bijection from a connected space into a disconnected one, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If there was such a function, its restriction $(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ would have to be injective and only miss one point i.e $f((0,1)) = \mathbb R -{f(0)}$. This set is disconnected. This can't be true because $(0,1)$ is connected and the image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected.